# auto slideshow with fade in AND fade_out in Android using animations only fade-in

Tags: java, android, slideshow, animated

I have a problem with a imageView in a area that I want to have a "auto-slideshow" between 4 pictures (downloaded from web-URL) 
I want a fade in and fade out change between the pictures.
the only thing I get to work is slideshow with:

fade in to a picture, and then "reset" the view blank, and then fade in a new image..

and not:
fade in to a picture, and then fade in a new image..
or: fade in to a picture, and then fade out to blank an then in a new image..

do you have any ideas?

here is my code: //I reduced the "get URL bitmap" a bit..

```js
public class SliderActivity extends Activity {
 
 public int currentimageindex=0;
 Timer timer;
 TimerTask task;
 ImageView slidingimage;
 public boolean ok;
 public Bitmap bm;
 public Bitmap bm0,bm1,bm2,bm3;
 String url11 = "https://www.weblink/pic1.png"; 
 String url22 = "https://www.weblink/pic2.png";
 String url33 = "https://www.weblink/pic3.png";
 String url44 = "https://www.weblink/pic4.png";
 String[] URLlink = {url11,url22,url33,url44};
 Bitmap[] IMAGE_IDS = { bm0, bm1, bm2,bm3 };
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mygame);        
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        downloadPicToArray();        
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             AnimateandSlideShowout();
             AnimateandSlideShow();
            }
        };  
        int delay = 1; // delay.. 1 sec = 1000.
        int period = 20000; // repeat every...1 sec. (2000)
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
          mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    private void downloadPicToArray() {
     try {
      BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
      bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
      bm0 = loadBitmap(URLlink[0], bmOptions);
      bm1 = loadBitmap(URLlink[1], bmOptions);
      bm2 = loadBitmap(URLlink[2], bmOptions);
      bm3 = loadBitmap(URLlink[3], bmOptions);
     }
     catch (...){
     }
     IMAGE_IDS[0] = bm0;
     IMAGE_IDS[1] = bm1;
     IMAGE_IDS[2] = bm2;
     IMAGE_IDS[3] = bm3;
 }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            if (in == null){
             bitmap = null;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
         bitmap = null;         
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
         inputStream = null;
        }
        return inputStream;
    }
    
 public void onClick(View v) {
    
        finish();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
      }
    
    private void AnimateandSlideShow() {
     Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
     Animation fadeinimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);  
     Animation fadeoutimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);        
     
     slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
     
      //slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);
      slidingimage.setImageBitmap(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);     
      currentimageindex++;}
    
    private void AnimateandSlideShowout() {
     Animation fadeoutimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
     slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
     slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);
  slidingimage.startAnimation(fadeoutimage);
    }
    
     
    
    
}
```

And the animations is like this:

```
  //fade out

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <alpha
          android:fromAlpha="1.0"
          android:toAlpha="0.0"
          android:duration="2000">
      </alpha>
  </set>


  //fade in
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <set
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            
      android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2000">
      </alpha>
  </set>
```